# Setting data that belongs to a User in iron router

Tags: meteor, iron-router

```
Router.route('/settings', {
  name: 'settings',
  data: function() {
    return Settings.findOne({userId: Meteor.user()._id});
  }
});
```

It's showing an error in the browser:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '_id' of undefined

---

Any suggestions on how to grab the settings record for a logged in user?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Meteor logging in process usually takes a few ms to get ready, meanwhile `Meteor.user()` will return `undefined` and the first execution of your route `data` method will fail.

You can use `Meteor.userId()` to avoid this from happening until the user is connected for real.

```
Router.route('/settings', {
  name: 'settings',
  data: function() {
    return Settings.findOne({
      userId: Meteor.userId()
    });
  }
});
```

Comment: Hi, this worked...but can you explain why adding Meteor.user() && before it works???  would the first run have userId as undefined and will Settings.findOne still run but only looking for userId:'undefined' ??  and then finally it will rerun with the correct value once reactivity happens??

Comment: Exactly, but just use `Meteor.userId` instead.